# How to request page messaging permissions on facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

When using facebook apps like chatfuel and manychat (which are bot creation platforms), these apps request permissions that allow them to manage my pages and send messages.

I want to create a similar app that allows users to send messages from their pages through my app, but I can't find how to request such permissions in Facebook's documentation.

[image: ManyChat's permissions, these are the permissions I want my app to request also.]

Comment: did you check out the official docs for facebooks messenger bots already? they are pretty good, and that´s where you need to start.

Comment: did you also try to create a bot on your own? there is example code and a very good step by step tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start

Comment: @luschn yes i can request these permissions for my own bot (I did that and it worked). but now i want to create an app that powers bots for other people/pages.

Comment: it works the same way, you just need to send it in for review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/launch

Comment: no, when using chatfuel and manychat it works instantly, without being reviewed by facebook

Comment: of course, because you are using THEIR bot, and THEIR bot is already approved

Comment: then how can I make my app request from users to connect MY (approved) bot to THEIR page?

Comment: You let a page admin login to your app, and grant it the necessary permissions. And then you subscribe your app to the page for messenger webhook updates ...

Comment: @CBroe that's exactly what I'm trying to do! how can i make my app request those permissions from the page admin?

Comment: By implementing Facebook Login ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score -1):

You need to be given the administrator role for each Page, then connect your app to the Page and generate a page-scoped token for each one.

Comment: _“You need to be given the administrator role for each Page”_ - no, you don’t. The usual way to make this work, is that a page admin logs into your app, and grants it the necessary permissions.